# Process(application) is active but is not shown anywhere on the desktop. How to open its window?

Tags: unity, 16.04, skype, window, mendeley

On Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity, sometimes when I start application and then if I close the window (it happens to Skype) or just lock the system (Mendeley) the icon of the application disappears from the menubar. Also I cannot Alt-Tab to it. System monitor shows that the process is still active.
The same happens if I start the application from a terminal - the terminal window is still busy with a process, but I didn't find a way to open the window corresponding to the process ( Ctrl+Z and `fg` or `bg` doesn't do anything).
How can I open the application's window?

Comment: To find out if a window exists *at all*, we' d need to install wmctrl. Then run `wmctrl -l` to get the window list. If you find a matching window, copy its id (first string in the line) and run `wmctrl -ia <window_id>`. My guess is the window does not exist anymore.

Comment: You're right, there is no window for Skype. I still see the pop-up notifications though.

Comment: I don't use skype, but is there an indicator running?

Comment: No, there is no indicator

Comment: Sounds like a bug.

Comment: Might be. I noticed that Unity doesn't behave well in general, there are some other small annoying bugs related to window management. Is there a way to repair/reinstall it? Also, I think it is related to the fact that I have 2 displays, one of which is connected via HDMI and the second one via DP. DP doesn't seem to be handled well by OS in general.